# Network Wide CA

Tags: certificate-authority

Is it possible to create a network wide Certificate Authority that doesn't need to be manually added to each device that connects.

We have internal servers that host websites that are only accessible from the network.

I have created a CA and issued certificates to the websites so they can be accessed over HTTPS.

Currently, I need to add the CA public key manually to every device on the network which is very tedious. Is it possible to automate this process when devices connect to the network? This would (hopefully) need to work on Windows, OSX (MacOS), Linux, Android and iOS. I know that is probably a big ask but I can't be the only person who would find this useful.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, this is pretty easy: you should purchase all your certificates from a recognized CA. Your CA is not recognized yet, though.

**No**, there is no magic. Each certificate must have a trust root, the CA that is trusted by OS vendor. What does it mean: the certificates of all trusted CAs are shipped with an OS. Your certificates are issues by your private CA, and the certificate of your CA must be installed on each device as "trusted third party"

To get the feeling of the requirements that vendors impose on CAs have a look at [Microsoft Trusted Root Certificate](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc751157.aspx)

Until your CA is not recognized as Microsoft Certified CA you have to install the certificates more or less manually.

I'd recommend to install CA certificate as "trusted third party", then all certificated issued by your CA will be trusted automagicaly.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to create a network wide Certificate Authority that doesn't need to be manually added to each device that connects.

technically, yes, it is doable. In practice it is hard to get your root CA to be trusted across Internet PKI, because it is very expensive and requires real reasons (motivation) for that. Generally, there are two options:

1. your root CA certificate inclusion in common trusted root lists (including, Microsoft, Mozilla, Google, etc.). Each root programs may differ, may or may not charge for inclusion. Although, certain programs (like Microsoft Root Program) do not charge you for inclusion, it will be expensive in meeting requirements. For example, you will need to develop a certificate policy, certificate practice statement and pass annual external audits. Needless to mention, that you will have to spend big money in hardware, for example, HSM (hardware security module).
2. you are purchasing a subordinate CA certificate under globally trusted root. Some globally trusted commercial CAs offer this option to companies with big number of issued certificates. More details in my article: https://www.sysadmins.lv/blog-en/certification-authority-root-signing.aspx